# A/B split test using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have two HTML codes, and I want to split the traffic between the two codes, so every visitor visits the pages it will be shown randomly one of two codes, I tried this code but nothing was included, just blank space, the code is used on an HTML page.

```
<?php

if (rand(0,1) == 1)
{
   include ('ad1.html');
}
else
{
   include ('ad2.html');
};
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code looks ok. But you have to have it in a file with extension .php and execute it from your webserver , else it would not work.

Comment: Blank page can mean two things: 1.- Page is not really blank but you aren't inspecting the actual output (in many browsers you can do so with `Ctrl+U`) 2.- You get a server error but haven't configured the server to display anything (for that, check the status code in your browser's "Network" tab).